# Squarespace Javascript Not Loading

Tags: javascript, squarespace, video-embedding

I'm having an issue while trying to embed javascript into my squarespace coverpage. The script is to load a random video from vimeo when they press the play button. my current website has the same play button but it just plays whats newest its here http://www.andrewlozano.com/

the code im trying to use is this

```js
    var videos = [
        '238243092',
        '235209416',
        '187960907',
        '187960695',
        '187960573',
        '187960448',
        '187960364',
        '187960175',
        '187960026',
        '187959808',
        '187959623',
        '187959099',
    ];
    
    var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    var html='<div class="embed"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videos[index] + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
    document.write(html);
```

But while it works when testing it doesnt work in squarespace. I get a 404 not found error.

[website error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEKAU.jpg)

Any ideas as to what might be going on or whats messing it up? Any directions to look or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with `document.write()`. Use `Element.innerHTML = html;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var videos = [
    '238243092',
    '235209416',
    '187960907',
    '187960695',
    '187960573',
    '187960448',
    '187960364',
    '187960175',
    '187960026',
    '187959808',
    '187959623',
    '187959099',
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
var html='<div class="embed"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videos[index] + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.innerHTML = html;
```